# Number of rectangles in an n-by-n grid of points

Tags: discrete-geometry, lattices, enumerative-combinatorics

I am seeking a formula for the number of rectangles with vertices belonging to an $n \times n$ square grid of points. This is sequence [A085582](https://oeis.org/A085582) in the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/). Note that the grid in question has $n^2$ *points* but only $(n-1)^2$ *grid squares*, because the points are at the corners of the grid squares.

I have found a complicated formula, but I want a simpler and more efficient formula if possible, or an asymptotic estimate. My strategy is to count the rectangles with each slope, then add them together. By the slope of a rectangle, I mean the slope of the parallel sides whose slope is positive or zero.

The number of axis-aligned (slope 0) rectangles is
$${n\choose2}^2=\frac14 n^2 (n-1)^2$$
because the rectangle is bounded by two horizontal lines and two vertical lines. There are ${n\choose2}$ ways to choose the horizontal lines, and ${n\choose2}$ ways to choose the vertical lines.

The number of rectangles of slope 1 is
$$\frac1{12}n(n-1)^2(n-2),$$
but this is harder to prove. So the number of rectangles with slope 0 or 1 is
$$\frac14 n^2 (n-1)^2 + \frac1{12} n(n-1)^2(n-2) = \frac{n}6(n-1)^2(2n-1).$$

Let $R$ be a grid rectangle with slope
$0 < s/r < 1$, where $r$ and $s$ are relatively prime positive integers.
The vectors from the bottom vertex are $\langle ar, as\rangle$ and
$\langle -bs, br\rangle$ for some positive integers $a$ and $b$. So $R$ is contained in an axis-aligned bounding rectangle $A$ of width $(ar+bs)$ and height $(as+br)$.

[image: Non-aligned rectangle in square grid with bounding box]

The bounding rectangle $A$ can be translated in the $n\times n$ grid to $(n-ar-bs)(n-as-br)$ positions, proved that both factors are positive. Therefore, the number of rectangles with slope $s/r$ is equal to
$$\sum_{a,b>0\\ar+bs<n\\as+br<n} (n-ar-bs) (n-as-br).$$

We can calculate the number of rectangles of slope 1 by substituting $r=1$ and $s=1$
into the summation, but I will leave this to the reader.

The same formula counts the number of rectangles with slope $r/s > 1$. Therefore, the total number of rectangles in the $n \times n$ grid is given by
$$
f(n) = \frac{n}6 (n-1)^2 (2n-1) + 2 \sum (n-ar-bs)(n-as-br)
$$
where the sum is taken over all integer values of $a$, $b$, $r$, and $s$ that satisfy the following conditions:

- $a, b > 0$
- $0 < s < r < n$
- $\gcd(r, s) = 1$
- $ar + bs < n$
- $as + br < n$

Using this formula, I am able to calculate the first 1000 terms in about 8 seconds. Is there a more efficient formula, or can someone give an asymptotic approximation?

My Python script is below. The `farey_sequence()` function is adapted from the Wikipedia article on Farey sequences.

```
def farey_sequence(n: int):
    a, b, c, d = 0, 1, 1, n
    yield (a, b)
    while (c <= n):
        k = (n + b) // d
        a, b, c, d = c, d, k * c - a, k * d - b
        yield (a, b)

def a085582(n: int) -> int:
    count = 0
    for s, r in farey_sequence(n - 1):
        if r == 1: 
            continue
        h = w = n - r - s
        while h > 0 and w > 0:
            h1, w1 = h, w
            while h1 > 0 and w1 > 0:
                count += h1 * w1
                h1 -= s
                w1 -= r
            h -= r
            w -= s
    count *= 2
    count += (n-1)**2 * n * (2*n-1) // 6
    return count
```

Comment: If you generalise to an $m \times n$ grid, you can use inclusion-exclusion to reduce the bookkeeping costs of counting the rectangles whose axis-aligned bounding box is smaller than the full grid. A [naive implementation](https://gist.github.com/pjt33/d877da8340ebf2eb8b33dce1b565c244) gets the same asymptotic performance as your code, but about a 5x speedup. Replacing the section following "Calculate rectangles which use the full bounding box" with a version which factors `x` and `m-1-x` to construct divisors from the prime factorisation of `prod` gives asymptotic performance improvement.

Comment: To rephrase this bounding-box approach as a generating function, let $f_n(z) = \sum_{d \mid z} z^{d+n/d}$. Then the g.f. for the bivariate generalisation is $$\frac{x^2 y^2}{(1-x)^3 (1-y)^3} + \frac{xy \sum_{n \ge 1} f_n(x) f_n(y)}{(1-x)^2 (1-y)^2}$$